# Slicing pandas dataframe as per expression value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am working with Python Pandas & I have the below use-case -

I am using a parameter dictionary to accept user inputs & I have an input variable "Period" with a user value 10.

```
paramDict = {
                "Period":
                        {
                        "Description": "A Period to filter on.",
                        "ParameterType" : "Value",
                        "DataType": "Number",                        
                        "Value" : ['10']
                        }
             }
```

Now, I have a dataframe df_temp as below -

```
           CODE         POSTING_PERIOD         POSTING_VALUE
0         00152                 CDD01J                115084
1         00152                 CDD02J                115177
2         00152                 CDD03J                115271
3         00152                 CDD04J                115359
4         00152                 CDD05J                115359
5         00152                 CDD06J                115359
6         00152                 CDD07J                115359
7         00152                 CDD08J                115359
8         00152                 CDD09J                115359
9         00152                 CDD10J                115359
10        00152                 CDD11J                115359
11        00152                 CDD12J                115359
```

Now, based on the user input "10" in this case, I want only row 9 to be selected where df['POSTING_PERIOD'] = 'CDD10J'

Note: In case the user input is 1, we should be able to prefix 0 to 1 & then row 0 should be selected where df['POSTING_PERIOD'] = 'CDD01J'

Can you please help me on the same? Thanks

Comment: ``df_temp[df_temp['POSTING_PERIOD'].str[3:5] == paramDict['Period']['Value']]``

Comment: @joris - It helps. But in case the user input is "1", it doesn't select  df['POSTING_PERIOD'] = 'CDD01J'. What is the best way we can use the append prefix 0 logic in case user input is <10. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Upon further reflection simply use zfill to pad the string to length 2
zfill will turn a string into a string of specific length with padded zeros:

```
In [1]: '1'.zfill(2)
Out [1]: '01'
In [2]: '12'.zfill(2)
Out [2]: '12'
```

You can use standard string methods to grab a portion of the dataframe. Here that would look like

```
df_temp[df_temp.POSTING_PERIOD.str.contains(paramDict['Period']['Value'].zfill(2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending @joris code:

```
> user_input = paramDict['Period']['Value']
> df_temp[df_temp['POSTING_PERIOD'].str[3:5].astype(int) == int(user_input)]
   CODE POSTING_PERIOD  POSTING_VALUE
0   152         CDD01J         115084
```